# Is there anything like 'onMessageReceivedInTheBackground' in Pusher Beams library?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, pusher

We are using push notifications with Pusher Beams for our flutter app. Is there a away to change the notification body and title before pushing notification?

It has `onMessageReceivedInTheForeground` but that only runs when the app is running.

Do we have something like this but that listen in the background?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same question. can't find solution anywhere, let me know if you find it,
I have found this pusher beams explanation, but I couldn't crack how to use it, maybe it helps you
https://pusher.com/docs/beams/guides/handle-incoming-notifications/android/

Comment: @AliMohsin I have contacted them. They said they don't support `onbackground` callbacks.